# Git squash commits in a branch merged with master

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I have few commits in my branch, commit A, commit B, commit C, then I merged master in my branch due to which commit D, commit E, commit F are on top of my commits now. How do I squash commit A, B, C into a single commit?

Comment: This is tricky because you have a merge commit on top of A, B, and C.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this:

```
master      -----D---E---F--\
work_branch   \---A---B---C--* (merge-Point)
```

so you create a branch whose head is on C

```
git checkout <sha1 at C>

git checkout -b work_branch_2
```

Then with interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i
```

this will open an editor with list of actions to do on each commit:

```
pick <sha1 A>  comment A
pick <sha1 B>  comment B
pick <sha1 C>  comment C
```

on line commit B an C replace pick by squash

```
pick <sha1 A>  comment A
s <sha1 B>  comment B
s <sha1 C>  comment C
```

so you'll get to this:

```
master      -----D---E---F--\
work_branch   \---A---B---C--* (merge-Point)  
work_branch_2  \---A'
```

I suggest that after this you rebase instead of merging 
git rebase master

Note: you can create branch as you want for each of your tries just push the right one :)